# What's the difference between Nginx 'keepalive_time' and 'keepalive_timeout'?

Tags: nginx, http, keepalive, keep-alive

In official Nginx docs a new directive added since v1.19.10 named `keepalive_time 1h`:
[Nginx keepalive_time Doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_time)

> Limits the maximum time during which requests can be processed through one keep-alive connection. After this time is reached, the connection is closed following the subsequent request processing.

Once a keep-alive connection initiates by browser, `keepalive_timeout 75s` limits the time during witch the next static HTTP request could be sent. After 75s, the keep-alive connection will be terminated. Now my question is, what will be happened after `keepalive_time 1h`? The connection already closed after 75 seconds! Does this mean that Nginx can execute a request witch has sent in a keep-alive connection for 1 hour?

Please simply describe the differences with an example as much as possible.

Comment: Only an idle keep-alive connection is closed after 75s. If the connection remains active (i.e. the browser continues to make many requests) then it will be closed after 1h.

Comment: @RichardSmith Did I understand correctly: Every keep-alive connection that receives a new request in less than 75 seconds frequently, will last up to one hour at max (by `keepalive_time 1h`). Of course, it is clear that if there is no request in 75 seconds, it will be closed by `keepalive_timeout 75s`

Comment: That is my understanding from reading the documents.

Answer (score 3):

keepalive_timeout is the time where the server will keep an idle connection open. If you send a request and then do nothing on this connection, the server will shutdown the connection at 75s after your previous request. keepalive_time is the maximum duration where a connection can be kept open even if it is not idle. So, if your connection is idle (no requests are sent), the server will shut it down after 75s (keepalive_timeout). If your connection is not idle (you keep sending requests), the server will shut it down after 1 hour (keepalive_time).